# Remove widget name ("Widgetsmith") under iOS 14 home screen widgets?

Tags: ios, customization, widgets

The release of iOS 14 adds [Widgets on the Home Screen](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-14/features/) to iOS.

People have been using apps like [Widgetsmith](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/widgetsmith/id1523682319) and [Color Widgets](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/color-widgets/id1531594277) to add customizable 3rd-party widgets and change the look of their entire iOS home screen.

However, the question [everyone's asking](https://twitter.com/search?q=widgetsmith%20remove&f=live) is how to remove the widget name text from under the widget (as that "kills the vibe").

> ok but how do u remove the name widgetsmith from under its killing the vibe

Can iOS 14 widgets be added to the iOS home screen *without* the app name / widget name underneath the widget? How can we hide the "Widgetsmith" label?

[image: Widgetsmith]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to the question:

> Is there any possible way to remove the “Widgetsmith” title under the widget on the home screen? It ruins the vibe sometimes [(twitter)](https://twitter.com/jacob_gu3/status/1308211522368225283)

David Smith, the creator of Widgetsmith, replied:

> Unfortunately not.  Apple requires that the app name be below every widget. [(twitter)](https://twitter.com/_DavidSmith/status/1308211923490680832)

So it appears that it is **not currently possible** to remove the name label text underneath an iOS home screen widget.

This is an **iOS restriction**, similar to all app icons (used to) have their app name under them. The widget app developers have no control over the matter, and cannot choose to hide their name.

You're gonna see the word "Widgetsmith" a lot:

[image: Widgetsmith]

You can [send Product Feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/) to Apple so that this is hopefully addressed in a future version of iOS.

Answer (score 1):

This is the **MD Bank** app. I tried it and it does work, but it’s far too limited. You can only create one blank widget. There’s no option to add more widgets or change the icon.

So I guess if you want one widget without a title then this does work.

[image]

Comment: Which app? link?

Answer (score 0):

Widgets have been added to iPadOS 15, one year after iOS, and widgets on the iPad do **not** have titles under them.

- https://www.apple.com/ipados/ipados-15/
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211328

[image]

Comment: How does this help for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

actually, i found a loophole. but it only works for photo widgets, not the widgets that require constant updates like calendars, time, etc. first you need to put ur widget as usual and then take a screenshot of your homescreen. then open this app called “MD Blank” its basically a widget app with “transparent” widgets. then go to md blank and put ur widget screenshot. then remove the widget you added go into jiggle mode and add widget. click on the widget to edit it and arrange it to wherever it is on the screen, and now, no more widget name.

Comment: This answer would be much more useful with a link to the app you recommend :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it's very easy to set up widget without the bottom text, but it can only be a static widget (photo, text, etc..) and it's completely free.

*(Tested on IOS 16.x and 17 public and dev beta)*

---

1. Download **MD Blank** app from the App Store (https://apps.apple.com/cz/app/md-blank-cool-photo-widget/id1551277937)
2. Now you need to screenshot your homescreen with the widgets from widgetsmith and upload that screenshot to the app

[image: Homescreen screenshot] [image: Add to the app]

3. Now delete the widgets from your homescreen and add widgets from this app and if you hold and edit widget you can choose position, which is the position the photo widget was on the screenshot you made so just select that and boom, done

[image: Select position]

My homescreen after this:

[image: Homescreen]